# Prometheus query to count unique label values

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I want to count number of unique label values. Kind of like

```
select count (distinct a) from hello_info
```

For example if my metric 'hello_info' has labels a and b. I want to count number of unique a's. Here the count would be 3 for a = "1", "2", "3".

```
hello_info(a="1", b="ddd")
hello_info(a="2", b="eee")
hello_info(a="1", b="fff")
hello_info(a="3", b="ggg")
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
count(count by (a) (hello_info))
```

First you want an aggregator with a result per value of `a`, and then you can count them.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, the first count returns a matrix of metrics (where each value is a vector too), and running count on it returns a nonsensical value such as "1.3" ... any ideas?

Comment: I think this query returns a time series rather than a number of all values ever recorded for a particular label.

Answer (score 14):

Other example:
If you want to count the number of apps deployed in a kubernetes cluster based on different values of a label( ex:app):

```
count(count(kube_pod_labels{app=~".*"}) by (app))
```

Answer (score 10):

The `count(count(hello_info) by (a))` is equivalent to the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT
  time_bucket('5 minutes', timestamp) AS t,
  COUNT(DISTINCT a)
FROM hello_info
GROUP BY t
```

See [time_bucket()](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/time_bucket/) function description.

E.g. it returns the number of distinct values for `a` label per each `5-minute` interval by default - see [staleness docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness) for details about 5-minute interval.

If you need to calculate the number of unique values for `a` label over custom interval (for example, over the last day), then the following PromQL query must be used instead:

```
count(count(last_over_time(hello_info[1d])) by (a))
```

The custom interval - `1d` in the case above - can be changed to an arbitrary value - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-durations) for possible values, which can be used there.

This query uses [last_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#last_over_time) function for selecting all the time series, which were [active](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/FAQ.html#what-is-an-active-time-series) during the last day. Time series can stop receiving new samples and become inactive at any time. Such time series aren't captured with simple `count(...) by (a)` after 5 minutes of inactivity. New deployments in Kubernetes and [horizontal pod autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) are the most frequent source of big number of inactive time series (aka [high churn rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/FAQ.html#what-is-high-churn-rate)).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the following:

```
count(count by (a)(delta(hello_info[10m]) > 0)) OR on() vector(0)
```

It counts the number of distinct non-zero metrics.