# Prometheus - Count increase in metrics for a given metric label

Tags: prometheus

I have the following counter metrics

```
9:00 AM message_counter{deviceid="1", messagetype="event1"}
9:01 AM message_counter{deviceid="1", messagetype="event2"}
9:02 AM message_counter{deviceid="2", messagetype="event1"}
9:03 AM message_counter{deviceid="3", messagetype="event2"}
9:04 AM message_counter{deviceid="4", messagetype="event1"}
9:05 AM message_counter{deviceid="3", messagetype="event2"}
```

How do I count the number of active devices for the last 2minutes which is 2(device id 3 and 4)?

Comment: This looks like distinct logged events. Prometheus data is, typically, increasing metrics. You may be using the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Also, we wary of 'series explosion'. Prometheus will create a new series for every unique set of labels. If you have say, 10 000 devices and 100 messagetypes, you'll end up with a million series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a similar question to [Prometheus query to count unique label values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882134/prometheus-query-to-count-unique-label-values). But here you only want metrics that have increased over the last two minutes.

You'll need to look at items with non-zero rates over the past 2 minutes:

```
count(count by (deviceid) (rate(message_counter[2m]) > 0))
```